# Prestashop path to image in php file

Tags: image, path, prestashop

i am using PrestaShop 1.4.8.2

i neet to generate xml file with products and i found a script. Everything works fine except image path (path is for old image file system, i am using new file system).

Now image path is: http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/57-56-large.jpg

But images are located in: 
    http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/1/0/0/3/17-32-large.jpg
    http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/2/0/0/3/61-50-large.jpg
    http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/3/1/6/3/29-75-large.jpg
    http://www.mydomain.com/img/p/3/0/4/3/25-11-large.jpg
    ...

this line get image path:

```
http://www.mydomain.com".__PS_BASE_URI__."img/p/".$image[0]['id_product']."-".$image[0]['id_image']."-large.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

why are you using the `getProductLink` function? It return the correct link for product/category/supplier/manufacturer. If you want to get the correct link to a product image use `$link->getImageLink($name, $ids, $type = NULL)`.

```
@param string $name rewrite link of the image
@param string $ids id part of the image filename - can be "id_product-id_image" (legacy support, recommended) or "id_image" (new)
@param string $type
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, i am sorry, my mistake. I posted wrong code, i edited my question, so please check the line again. Thank you!

Comment: Wrong image path and when i try to follow path there is no image :(

Comment: But why you are't using $link->getImageLink() function?

Comment: it was not my idea :) i found a post in prestashop forum and used that code.

here is the original post: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/71267-solved-script-to-export-productlist-as-xml/page__st__20

Comment: I still have the same problem. Here is the line, which gets wrong image path: echo "<image>http://www.mydomain.com".__PS_BASE_URI__."img/p/".$image[0]['id_product']."-".$image[0]['id_image']."-large.jpg</image>\n";